# SQL One-to-Many relation

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I am designing a database for an application and i have encountered a problem.
The database is supposed to track patients and their pills.
I figured that I needed a **relational database** and that is what I am trying to implement and this is my problem:

*I need a patient to be associated with multiple pills, not just one.*

All I've found online was a table where pills were associated with the person and not the other way around.

**Thanks for helping**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a One-to-Many, but a Many-to-Many relation: a patient could have more pills, but the same kind of pill could be taken by a lot of patient.

SO you should have 3 tables:

The Patient table

```
id | name | surname
```

The pills table

```
id | name | pharmaceutic_company
```

The realtion table

```
id_patient | id_pill | date
```

Comment: Yes, it is. This is a more complete solution